# Why Application insight not showing Failed requests, Server response time, Server requests and Availability?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have two project Web app and Web API. I have integrated application insight to them simply by right-click on my project and choosing option `configure application insight`. I can see my `live metrics` working fine but in the `Overview` page I don't see any movement in graphs. I have attached the screenshot of the not-working-graph.

[image]

I just noticed that when i am integrating application normally as stated above then its working fine but when i am trying to change the application insight by changing the key of application insight at specific location then the issue is creating. Can anyone help me why its working differently just by changing the application key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, The Instrumentation Key is the bridge that binds your application to Application Insights through which you monitor all the changes that occur in your application.

> Instrumentation Key is the key integration point between your application and the Application Insights. If you create the Application Insights directly using Visual Studio; Visual Studio takes care of linking between your application and the key.

So changing the Instrumentation key from Application insights can make the live metrics work differently since the link is broken. If you are trying to add another resource's i.e., Application insights' instrumentation key (depending upon your business requirement), then you can see that the metrics get logged in that resource.

**REFERENCES:** [ABHIJIT JANA - Instrumentation key in application insights](https://findanyanswer.com/goto/376235)

Comment: How can i change the application insight then ?

Comment: @Psychonaut007 you can replace the previous resource instrumentation key with the new one. If you are trying to change the application insights instrumentation key dynamically such as in cases where you have different environments then try checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257252/change-instrumentation-key-for-logging-in-asp-net-core-using-application-insight and https://medium.com/aerion-technologies/dynamically-using-instrumentation-keys-with-azure-application-insights-d736de5b59fc .